# where is lstrncpy's head file?

Tags: string, copy

I know lstrcpy is used for string copy for both unicode and ascii, 
But I can not use lstrncpy, because I can't find the head file.
What is the name of the head file, I googled it, and find someone is using it.
Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As per the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms647490%28VS.85%29.aspx) include `Windows.h`

Answer (score 1):

It is delcared in Winbase.h you need to include Windows.h

James.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the length anyway, you can simply use `memcpy (..., length * sizeof (char_type));` which will work for any character type.

Answer (score 0):

you must use [strsafe.h](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms647466(VS.85).aspx) or just include windows.h

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking about the Windows lstrcpy() function, it is declared in winbase.h, which normally gets included via windows.h

Comment: Woops think you just pipped me to the post!...no pun intended